# border radius button don't work on android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I use `Xamarin.Forms`, I try set  `BorderRadius = 10` or  `BorderRadius = Device.OnPlatform<int>(iOS: 0, Android: 10, WinPhone: 10)` . On UWP it's ok (both ways) but on android BorderRadius in not apply

Comment: On which control do you need this `BorderRadius`?

Comment: `Button`  I want change `BorderRadius` from `Button`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Button I want change BorderRadius from Button

Problem is with the `ButtonRenderer` of Xamarin Forms for Android. There are two kinds of `ButtonRenderer`s for Android:

[ButtonRenderer](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android/Renderers/ButtonRenderer.cs) under `Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android` namespace and [ButtonRenderer](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android/AppCompat/ButtonRenderer.cs) under `Xamarin.Forms.Platfrom.Android.AppCompat` namespace.

By default in Xamarin.Forms, it will use the `ButtonRenderer` under the `Xamarin.Forms.Platfrom.Android.AppCompat` namespace to render the button, but this renderer doesn't create a border for `Button`, so the `BorderRadius` properties doesn't work for the buttons which are rendered with this renderer.

To solve this issue, you can create your own custom button with [Custom Renderer](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/custom-renderer/), and use the `ButtonRenderer` under `Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android` namespace for rendering.

For creating a Custom renderer for your Button, you can refer to this [discussion](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/23039/button-bordercolor-not-showing-on-android-4-4).

Answer (score 0):

Another solution

Change your renderer constructor like this.

```
public CustomButtonRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
{

}
```